# Rails 3 and Ajax confusion

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In short, I don't understand ajax with rails. I did this [tutorial](http://tekn0t.net/ajax-example-with-rails-3-and-jquery) a little while ago and I can get it to work. No problems. The problems seem arise when I have more than one model.

For example, if I have a model "cats",  I use the tutorial to implement some ajax, works nicely - each time I add a new cat to the list, it appears at the top without reloading the page. Then I add a "dogs" model, and I render the _dog.html.erb file in the cats index and call on it with something like @dogs.each do |dog| etc.

Now I need to implement the ajax for the dogs, but do I put the ajax files into create.js.erb in the dogs folder or in the cats create.js.html folder? I've tried both, no success. The first model, in this example cats, will continue to work, but the others don't. I know that its half working because the page doesn't reload when I hit enter, but nothing is generated either. I've checked the id's, all correct.

Is there anything else I should be looking for? My logic says that if i'm in the cats index and rendering something from _dog.html.erb, I should put all the create ajax in the cats create.js.html folder….

Help is more than appreciated.

Also, just as a small second question, I read another [tutorial](http://keithschacht.com/getting-ajax-to-work-in-rails-3-with-jquery/) and it advised me to delete everything in the public/javascripts folder except "application.js", which in my case is blank. I haven't because ajax is working, just not for the other models. Should I take the tutorials advise?

Thanks again.

Update

This is the code from "show" in the cats controller.

```
@dog = Dog.new

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
end
```

Update 2

Ok, so "Cats" is really "Games", and "Dogs" is really "Features". I used the cats and dogs examples because I thought in theory it would be easier, sorry if it made it more confusing :).

The code - the ajax for creating games in the games index is working, but the ajax for creating features in the games show is not. The games show is where I want to create new features using ajax. the features are created but only viewable after a page reload.

```
    class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @games = Game.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    @game = Game.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @gameid = Game.find(params[:id])
    @features = Feature.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8, :conditions => {:game_id => @gameid})
    @feature = Feature.new
         respond_to do |format|
           format.html
    end




  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(params[:game])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to(games_url,
                                  :notice => 'game was successfully created.') }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to(games_url) }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @game.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(games_url) }
      format.js
    end
  end
end





class FeaturesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @features = Feature.all
    @feature = Feature.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def create
    @feature = Feature.new(params[:feature])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feature.save
        format.html { redirect_to(features_url,
                                  :notice => 'feature was successfully created.') }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to(features_url) }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @feature = Feature.find(params[:id])
    @feature.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(features_url) }
      format.js
    end
  end
end



(features/create.js.erb)
$('#features').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render(@feature)) %>');
$('#features > li:first').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
$('#features_form > form')[0].reset();

(games/create.js.erb)
$('#games').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render(@game)) %>');
$('#games > li:first').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
$('#game_form > form')[0].reset();


(games/index)
<h1>Games</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="main">


      <ul id="games">
        <% @games.each do |game| %>
            <%= render 'game', :game => game %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <% if signed_in? %>

          <div id="game_form">
            <%= render 'form' %>
          </div>

      <% else %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td class="sidebar">


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


(games/show)
<h1>Features</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="main">

      <h2>Features</h2>

      <div id="features_form">
            <%= render 'features/form' %>
        </div>

      <ul id="features" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
        <% @features.each do |feature| %>
            <%= render 'features/feature', :feature => feature %>
        <% end %>
              <%= will_paginate @features, :class => 'pagination' %>

      </ul>

    </td>
    <td class="sidebar">


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what Controller/Action are you calling when dealing with dogs? coudl you please post some code?

Comment: I updated it, is that the code you want? I'm new to rails so i'm not so good with the names for codes.

Comment: ok, show is the Action you are asking to Dog controller. Actually it's quite strange. How did you get that code? I mean, the show action usually extracts an object from DB and pass it to the view. You are actually creating a new object dog. Could you post cats_controller, dog_controller, js.erb files and cats/index to review?

Comment: I think you may want to review some more basic tutorials before diving into Ajax, like the one by Michael Hartl or the Rails guides. It'll make understanding Ajax in Rails easier if you know the basics first, because that show action seems a bit off.

Comment: I copied it straight from the first tutorial I listed. Everything else seems to work ok. Thanks Juan and Nick for your help so far :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work. All that was missing was `format.js` under the `format.html` in show in the games controller. Like this:

```
 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @gameid = Game.find(params[:id])
    @features = Feature.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8, :conditions => {:game_id => @gameid})
    @feature = Feature.new
         respond_to do |format|
           format.html
           format.js
    end
  end
```

I guess the strange thing is that games didn't need this to execute ajax...

Cheers guys for the help